# Unable to read Image: error: A value of type 'Future<PickedFile>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow-lite

```
300: pickImage() async {
301:    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
302:    final image = _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
303:    if (image == null) return null;
304:    setState(() {
305:      _loading = true;
306:      _image = image;
307:    });
308:    classifyImage(image);
309:  }
```

Throws the errors at:

- 306: error: A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.
- 308: error: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.

I have added `// @dart=2.9`  at the head of the `main.dart`.

I am new to Flutter-Tflite, can someone provide guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because it is an asynchronous function, therefore you must use the "await".

`final image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);`